# How to use 'Where Not In' in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to create a query where I get data from a table and I use INNER JOIN and Where Not In, I was able to adapt the INNER JOIN part, but in 'WHERE NOT IN' I tried using 'WhereNotIn' from Laravel 5.4. But it returns the error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
SELECT
        em.erp_mlbid AS category_id

            FROM 
                erp_product AS ep
            INNER JOIN
                erp_product_category AS epc ON epc.erp_productid = ep.erp_productid
            INNER JOIN
                erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory AS emc ON emc.erp_categoryid = epc.erp_categoryid
            INNER JOIN
                erp_mlb_category AS em ON em.erp_mcid = emc.erp_mlbcategoryid    
            WHERE
                ep.erp_productid NOT IN (
                        SELECT
                            epm.erp_productid
                        FROM
                            erp_product_to_mlb AS epm
                )
                AND ep.erp_quantity > 0
                AND ep.erp_status > 0
            LIMIT
                    10,10
```

So I created this in my application:

```
$categoria = DB::table('erp_product')
                            ->join('erp_product_category','erp_product_category.erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product.erp_productid')
                            ->join('erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_categoryid', '=','erp_product_category.erp_categoryid')
                            ->join('erp_mlb_category', 'erp_mlb_category.erp_mcid', '=', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_mlbcategoryid')
                            ->select('erp_mlb_category.erp_mlbid')
                            ->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid', function($query){
                                $query->select('erp_productid')
                                       ->from('erp_product')
                                       ->where('erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product_category.erp_productid');
                            })
                            ->get();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: does removing the `'='` in the `whereNotIn` fix anything?

Comment: I fixed but my code return the same data. Ignoring the condition.

Comment: `select('erp_productid')` needs to be `select('erp_product.id')` same with the where

Comment: Same error, return the data :/

Comment: maybe try replacing `get()` with `toSql()` and examining the sql your query is producing and look for mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This lines of code is wrong:

```
->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid', function($query){
  $query->select('erp_productid')
  ->from('erp_product')
  ->where('erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product_category.erp_productid');
})
```

- remove this line `->where('erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product_category.erp_productid')` cause there is not join here.
- you can't say `->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid'` and `$query->select('erp_productid')->from('erp_product')` in the same order **whereNotIn** to check the value in the **first_column** not exists in the **second_column** not in same **first_column**.

So, clear this line `->where('erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product_category.erp_productid')` and check the right name to put in `$query->select('right_column_name')->from('right_table_name')`.

Comment: Undefined offset: 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids= DB::table('erp_product')->pluck('erp_productid')

$categoria = DB::table('erp_product')
                            ->join('erp_product_category','erp_product_category.erp_productid', '=', 'erp_product.erp_productid')
                            ->join('erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_categoryid', '=','erp_product_category.erp_categoryid')
                            ->join('erp_mlb_category', 'erp_mlb_category.erp_mcid', '=', 'erp_mlbcategory_erpcategory.erp_mlbcategoryid')
                            ->select('erp_mlb_category.erp_mlbid')
                            ->whereNotIn('erp_product.erp_productid',$ids)
                            ->get();
```

Comment: Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string;

Comment: Code returns timeout.